# Google Analytics API PHP

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I want to make querys with the `Google Analytic API`. I work with the Google Developers Guide and some other examples. With the HelloAnalytics example i have to use the Service Account login and it works. In another example I use the Webapp authentication. This is my used code

```
 <?php
// Load the Google API PHP Client Library.
require_once realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/GoogleClientApi/src/Google/autoload.php');
$client = new Google_Client();

$app_name = 'API Project';
$analytics_client_id = 'XXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$analytics_client_secret = 'XXXXX';
$analytics_developerToken = 'XXXXX';
$redirect_uri = "http://bh.cylab.cybay-ebox.de/start.php";
$scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly";

$client->setApplicationName($app_name);
$client->setClientId($analytics_client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($analytics_client_secret);
$client->setDeveloperKey($analytics_developerToken);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client->setScopes(array($scope));

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $client->authenticate();
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {
    $loginUrl = sprintf("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=%s&state=%s&redirect_uri=%s&response_type=code&client_id=%s&access_type=%s",$scope,$state,$redirect_uri,$analytics_client_id,$access_type);
    header('Location: '.$loginUrl);
}

$analytics = new Google_AnalyticsService($client);

//get Accounts Hierachien abrufen!

$accounts = $analytics->management_accounts->listManagementAccounts();
$a_items = $accounts->getItems();

echo count($a_items)." Accounts<br>";
if(count($a_items)!=0)
{
    foreach($a_items as $account)
    {
        echo 'Account ID: '.$account->getID().'<br>';
        echo 'Account Name: '.$account->getName().'<br>';
        //get web properties
        $webProperties = $analytics->management_webproperties->listManagementWebproperties($account->getID());
        $w_items = $webProperties->getItems();

        echo count($w_items)." Webproperties<br>";
        if(count($w_items)!=0)
        {
            foreach($w_items as $webproperty)
            {
                echo '*Webproperty ID: '.$webproperty->getId().'<br>';
                echo '*Webproperty Name: '.$webproperty->getName().'<br>';
                //get profiles
                $profiles = $analytics->management_profiles->listManagementProfiles($account->getID(), $webproperty->getId());
                $p_items = $profiles->getItems();

                //get analytics data
            }
        }
    }
}
function getVisits($analytics, $from, $to, $profile_id, $channel)
{
    $optParams = array(
        'dimensions' => 'ga:source,ga:keyword',
        'sort' => '-ga:sessions',
        'filters' => 'ga:medium=='.$channel
    );

    return $analytics->data_ga->get(
        'ga:'.$profile_id,
        $from = '2015-08-10',
        $to = '2015-08-11',
        'ga:sessions',
        $optParams
    );
}

$result = getVisits($analytics, $i, $profile->getId(), $channel);
$rows = getValue($result);
if($rows != null)
{
    foreach($rows as $result)
    {
        echo 'source: '.$result[0].'<br>';
        echo 'keyword: '.$result[1].'<br>';
        echo 'visits:'.$result[2].'<br>';
    }
}
function getValue($results)
{
    if(count($results->getRows())>0)
    {
        $rows = $results->getRows();
        return $rows;
    }
    return null;
}
```

I replaced the PW's with XXXX i get a Failure Message in the Browser like this

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for Google_Client::authenticate(), called
>   in /data/kunden/cylab/BH/produktion/web/htdocs_final/start.php on line
>   21 and defined in
>   /data/kunden/cylab/BH/produktion/web/htdocs_final/GoogleClientApi/src/Google/Client.php
>   on line 125
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message
>   'Invalid code' in
>   /data/kunden/cylab/BH/produktion/web/htdocs_final/GoogleClientApi/src/Google/Auth/OAuth2.php:88
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /data/kunden/cylab/BH/produktion/web/htdocs_final/GoogleClientApi/src/Google/Client.php(128):
>   Google_Auth_OAuth2->authenticate(NULL, false) #1
>   /data/kunden/cylab/BH/produktion/web/htdocs_final/start.php(21):
>   Google_Client->authenticate() #2 {main} thrown in
>   /data/kunden/cylab/BH/produktion/web/htdocs_final/GoogleClientApi/src/Google/Auth/OAuth2.php
>   on line 88

I hope you can help me.

The working `HelloAnalytics` is

```
<?php

    function getService()
    {
      // Creates and returns the Analytics service object.

      // Load the Google API PHP Client Library.
    require_once realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/GoogleClientApi/src/Google/autoload.php');


      // Use the developers console and replace the values with your
      // service account email, and relative location of your key file.
      $service_account_email = 'XXXXXf@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
      $key_file_location = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/client_secrets.p12";

      // Create and configure a new client object.
      $client = new Google_Client();
      $client->setApplicationName("HelloAnalytics");
      $analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);

      // Read the generated client_secrets.p12 key.
      $key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
      $cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
          $service_account_email,
          array(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY),
          $key
      );
      $client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
      if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
      }

      return $analytics;
    }

    function getFirstprofileId(&$analytics) {
      // Get the user's first view (profile) ID.

      // Get the list of accounts for the authorized user.
      $accounts = $analytics->management_accounts->listManagementAccounts();

      if (count($accounts->getItems()) > 0) {
        $items = $accounts->getItems();
        $firstAccountId = $items[0]->getId();

        // Get the list of properties for the authorized user.
        $properties = $analytics->management_webproperties
            ->listManagementWebproperties($firstAccountId);

        if (count($properties->getItems()) > 0) {
          $items = $properties->getItems();
          $firstPropertyId = $items[0]->getId();

          // Get the list of views (profiles) for the authorized user.
          $profiles = $analytics->management_profiles
              ->listManagementProfiles($firstAccountId, $firstPropertyId);

          if (count($profiles->getItems()) > 0) {
            $items = $profiles->getItems();

            // Return the first view (profile) ID.
            return $items[0]->getId();

          } else {
            throw new Exception('No views (profiles) found for this user.');
          }
        } else {
          throw new Exception('No properties found for this user.');
        }
      } else {
        throw new Exception('No accounts found for this user.');
      }
    }

    function getResults(&$analytics, $profileId) {
        //Calls the Core Reporting API and queries
        // Gewünschte Metriken hier abfragen! 
       return $analytics->data_ga->get(
           'ga:' . $profileId,
           '2015-08-10',
           '2015-08-11',
           'ga:sessions'
                  );
    }

    function printResults(&$results) {
      // Parses the response from the Core Reporting API and prints
      // the profile name and total sessions.
      if (count($results->getRows()) > 0) {

        // Get the profile name.
        $profileName = $results->getProfileInfo()->getProfileName();

        // Get the entry for the first entry in the first row.
        $rows = $results->getRows();
        $sessions = $rows[0][0];

        // Print the results.
        print "First view (profile) found: $profileName\n";
        print "Total sessions: $sessions\n";
      } else {
        print "No results found.\n";
      }
    }

    $analytics = getService();
    $profile = getFirstProfileId($analytics);
    $results = getResults($analytics, $profile);
    printResults($results);

    ?>
```

Maybe I should combine the two codes but I don't know how?

Comment: What kind of application are trying to build? A web application? if so use this hello world example: https://goo.gl/vhIUkM if you are using a service account? use this example: https://goo.gl/76hl8c Describe how you would like users to interact with your application and whose data you are trying to access and that should inform you on how you should proceed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is difficult to say because i cant rly see the diffrence between the Service- and Webapp account for my Project. In my project i should create automaticly Seo Reports from driffrent tools like Google Analytics, Brandwatch, Sistrix, Adwords and so on. The Goal is to create 1 interface where i can insert dateranges and parameters to get the informations of all tools. At the moment Im writing the documentation for this Project and want to test the parameters to get a overview about them. So we can make a list which are needed and how they can requested.

Comment: One key difference is that a web application is usually externally facing. where outside users will access their own data. A user would come to your website authorize it to access their data and then your application runs using their data. A Service account type applications is for accessing your own private data. It can collect the data as a back end process or on demand and then securely serve that data into any type of system, CRM, database, etc...

Answer (score 0):

**Service account**

Before you can access any of the Google APIs you need to first create your application in the Google Developers console.    If you create a service account authentication you will only be able to access your own Google Analytics account.

A service account doesn’t need to prompt a user for access because you have to set it up. Go to the Google Analytics website in the Admin section for the Account you want to retrieve data from. Add the service account email address as a user.  This is very important it must be at the **account level**  just give them read access.

```
<?php
   require_once 'Google/autoload.php';
   session_start();     
/************************************************   
 The following 3 values an befound in the setting   
 for the application you created on Google      
 Developers console.         Developers console.
 The Key file should be placed in a location     
 that is not accessable from the web. outside of 
 web root.       web root.

 In order to access your GA account you must    
 Add the Email address as a user at the     
 ACCOUNT Level in the GA admin.         
 ************************************************/
    $client_id = '[Your client id]';
    $Email_address = '[YOur Service account email address Address]';     
    $key_file_location = '[Locatkon of key file]';      

    $client = new Google_Client();      
    $client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
    $key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);    

    // seproate additional scopes with a comma   
    $scopes ="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly";  

    $cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials($Email_address,         
                             array($scopes),        
                             $key);     

    $client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
    if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {        
         $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);      
    }       

    $service = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);



    //Adding Dimensions
    $params = array('dimensions' => 'ga:userType'); 
    // requesting the data  
    $data = $service->data_ga->get("ga:89798036", "2014-12-14", "2014-12-14", "ga:users,ga:sessions", $params );     
?>

<html>   
Results for date:  2014-12-14<br>
    <table border="1">   
        <tr>     
        <?php    
        //Printing column headers
        foreach($data->getColumnHeaders() as $header){
             print "<td><b>".$header['name']."</b></td>";       
            }       
        ?>      
        </tr>       
        <?php       
        //printing each row.
        foreach ($data->getRows() as $row) {        
            print "<tr><td>".$row[0]."</td><td>".$row[1]."</td><td>".$row[2]."</td></tr>";   
        }    
?>      
<tr><td colspan="2">Rows Returned <?php print $data->getTotalResults();?> </td></tr>     
</table>     
</html>
```

code ripped from [Google Analytics Service account](http://www.daimto.com/google_service_account_php/) tutorial

**Web application**

A web application credentials are used for Oauth2 when you want to be able to request a user authenticate you giving you permission to access there data.

```
<?php    

    require_once 'Google/autoload.php';
    session_start(); 

    // ********************************************************  //
    // Get these values from https://console.developers.google.com
    // Be sure to enable the Analytics API
    // ********************************************************    //
    $client_id = '[Your Client Id]';
    $client_secret = '[Your client Secret]';
    $redirect_uri = '[Your Redirect URI]';


    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
    $client->setClientId($client_id);
    $client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
    $client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
    $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'));
    $client->setAccessType('offline');   // Gets us our refreshtoken


    //For loging out.
    if ($_GET['logout'] == "1") {
    unset($_SESSION['token']);
       }


    // Step 2: The user accepted your access now you need to exchange it.
    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {

        $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);  
        $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    }

    // Step 1:  The user has not authenticated we give them a link to login    
    if (!$client->getAccessToken() && !isset($_SESSION['token'])) {

        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();

        print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";
        }    


    // Step 3: We have access we can now create our service
    if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
        print "<a class='logout' href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?logout=1'>LogOut</a><br>";


        print "Access from google: " . $_SESSION['token']."<br>"; 

        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
        $service = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);    

        // request user accounts
        $accounts = $service->management_accountSummaries->listManagementAccountSummaries();


        foreach ($accounts->getItems() as $item) {

        echo "<b>Account:</b> ",$item['name'], "  " , $item['id'], "<br /> \n";

        foreach($item->getWebProperties() as $wp) {
            echo '-----<b>WebProperty:</b> ' ,$wp['name'], "  " , $wp['id'], "<br /> \n";    
            $views = $wp->getProfiles();
            if (!is_null($views)) {
                                // note sometimes a web property does not have a profile / view

                foreach($wp->getProfiles() as $view) {

                    echo '----------<b>View:</b> ' ,$view['name'], "  " , $view['id'], "<br /> \n";    
                }  // closes profile
            }
        } // Closes web property

    } // closes account summaries
    }


?>
```

code ripped from [Google Analytics Oauth2](http://www.daimto.com/google-oauth2-php/)  tutorial

Answer (score 0):

If you want to integrate the Google Analytics API with your application, you must have a Google API console project and enable Analytics API. For more details [Google Analytics API Integration & Example](http://www.apinotes.com/blog/info/2017/google-analytics-api/MQ==)

```
<?php
include 'CustomAnalytcs_class.php';
$service_account_email = 'apinotesdemo@active-future-171705.iam.gserviceaccount.com';
// Service account Email ID
$key_file_location = 'GoogleAnalytics-fa32e1a557ad.p12'; // P12 Format Private Key File
$analytics = new CustomAnalytcs_class($service_account_email, $key_file_location);
$realtimedata = $analytics->getRealtimeData(); // Get Real Time Data
$sessiondata = $analytics->getSessonData();// Get Real Time Session Data
?>
```